# Find and replace text in text file with environmental variable

Tags: vbscript, replace, environment-variables

I am wanting to setup a new library in Windows 7 for our users, however the Libraries cannot accept a variable in the path.

The library I am trying to setup is Downloads and I want it to point at %temp%\Download.
I've created a text file with the required info in it for the library, and now I just need a script that can read the file, find a string (I just made it up) C:\staging, and replace it with the actual path from the environmental variable (so instead of adding %temp%\Download, it would add C:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\download).

I can then save this file into the libraries folder and rename it, which should fix the problem.

Could someone please provide some assistance as I struggle with the vb scripts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is [.ExpandEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8116cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
>> WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%\Download")
>>
C:\DOCUME~1\eh\LOCALS~1\Temp\Download
>>
```

Comment: Hi Ekkehard, thanks for that.  That works perfectly to get the full path, but how do I now get that into the script.  All the scripts I've found reference the new words like this script.vbs "oldword" "newword", how do I get the full path into the "newword" area?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help on this one.  The full solution was posted in a spiceworks forum by Jake.  
See here: http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/410655-create-libraries-via-gpo-with-variables-in-path?page=1#entry-2765014

Thanks

Luke